# REST API approve / reject an user

Tags: rest

What is the proper way to structure a RESTful resource for approving or rejecting a user?

This resource is meant to review an user by administrator. Administrator can approve or reject a user request. The request needs to have `user_id` and `updated_status` that maybe is `approved` or `rejected`.

The two options that I have are:

1) Classified it to two apis:

```
PUT api/users/:user_id/approve/
PUT api/users/:user_id/reject/
```

OR

2)

```
PUT api/users/:user_id/review/
   -status passed through request body
```

Any advice or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't recall whether there is any concrete REST API design standard that people typically follow. I doubt there is any, but you do want to be aware of some `anti-patterns` which are considered as "poor REST design".

1) Overly dependent on `querystring`.

```
GET http://api.example.com/services?op=approve_request&userid=12345
```

This is a classic bad design, as the API `services` is too generic and non-descriptive.

You basically can do anything with just the API `services`. Also the use of HTTP method is incorrect as well, `GET` which depicts fetch/retrieve should be reserved for its purpose. For update it should be `PUT` and create should be `POST`.

Another bad point is maintainability, the underhood code is definitely going to be a nightmare as it is too general purpose.

2) Bad resource naming.

```
GET http://api.example.com/update_customer/12345
```

This one has got the noun and verb combined `update_customer`. It is usually better to name your `API` in nouns. E.g. `customer/account`.

This is more practical as doing a `DELETE` can meant by closing an account , `PUT` to modify details of an account, where modification details can be described in the request's payload.

Also, the HTTP method `GET` should not be used here.

In general you should not need to use the verbs like 'update', 'create' or 'delete' in the URL because the intended operation can be derived from the HTTP method verbs.

3) Confusing verb
`PUT http://api.example.com/customers/12345/update`

Again, verb should not be included in the `URL`. It is confusing because you have the `PUT` http method and the verb `update` is in there as well.

---

### Proposed solution

For your case. You have `user` and `request` as the resources.
I think the API can be designed as;

**Approve request**:

`PUT http://api.example.com/user/12345/request`

**Create new request**:

`POST http://api.example.com/user/12345/request`

**Reject request**:

`DELETE http://api.example.com/user/12345/request`

Instead of deleting the actual request, update status to `Reject`.

Comment: Hmm, I forgot that we should name API in nouns.

Comment: I am wondering that using **DELETE** in case we do not remove anything is the good way to structure ?

Comment: Not to worry. Having `api` in URL not a bad practise. I have seen established system and open source projects with their UI sitting as something like `http://www.ToanTran.com` then the server side of things would be `http://www.ToanTran.com/api/user/12345/request`.

Comment: No right or wrong answer here. Again, I have seen design that uses the `DELETE` method to close a customer's account like `DELETE http://xxx/customer/account` For tracerability, the system dont really remove the account from the database. It just marked the account record as expired.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `PUT` to reject a request. Same URL `PUT http://api.example.com/user/12345/request`, then in the body of HTTP request, maybe have a JSON object to say something like " { status = Reject } ". I think this may not be as clean as the original solution. Again, no right or wrong here.

Comment: Well done. It is also best when resources are plural. This means http://api.example.com/users/12345/request instead of http://api.example.com/user/12345/request

Answer (score 1):

To make this more RESTful, you have 2 real options:

1. You add an `approved` or `status` property to the user, that only an administrator is allowed to modifiy.
2. If you want to go the separate resource route, you shouldn't create 2 resources describing actions, but create a single resource describing state. So instead of `api/users/:user_id/approve` and `api/users/:user_id/reject`, there should be a single resource named something like `api/users/:user_id/approval-status`. This resource should contain the actual information that tells the client that the user was approved or not, and this may be changed by an admin.

As a rule of thumb, if there are verbs in your urls, you're likely doing something that's not RESTful. The verbs in your case are `approve`, `reject` and `review` and are definitely all wrong.

Comment: User model currently has the property named `status` . Single resource is good. I like @Samuel answer more. We can classify **approve** and **reject**  by method type :)